# How to scrape a table from any site and store it to data frame?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to **scrape** a table from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M
and store this data in python dataframe.
I have pulled the table but unable to pick the columns (Postcode, Borough, Neighbourhood)

My table looks like this:

```
<table class="wikitable sortable">
<tbody><tr>
<th>Postcode</th>
<th>Borough</th>
<th>Neighbourhood
</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>M1A</td>
<td>Not assigned</td>
<td>Not assigned
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>M2A</td>
<td>Not assigned</td>
<td>Not assigned
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>M3A</td>
<td><a href="/wiki/North_York" title="North York">North York</a></td>
<td><a href="/wiki/Parkwoods" title="Parkwoods">Parkwoods</a>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>M4A</td>
<td><a href="/wiki/North_York" title="North York">North York</a></td>
<td><a href="/wiki/Victoria_Village" title="Victoria Village">Victoria Village</a>
</td></tr>
...

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M'
response = requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})

df = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    Postcode = row.columns[1].get_text()
    Borough = row.columns[2].get_text()
    Neighbourhood = row.column[3].get_text()
    df.append([Postcode,Borough,Neighbourhood])
```

With the above code I am getting
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I googled it and got to know that I cannot do
Postcode = row.columns[1].get_text()
because of inline propery of the function.

I tried something else too but got some "Index error message".

It's simple. I need to traverse the row and goes on picking the three columns for each row and store it in a list. But I am not able to write it in a code.

Expected output is

```
 Postcode   Borough   Neighbourhood
    M1A     Not assigned Not assigned
    M2A     Not assigned Not assigned
    M3A     North York    Parkwoods
```

Comment: I don't know what is your expected output but you defined `columns` as `row.find_all('td')`
You do not need to specify `row.columns[1].get_text()`
You have to call `columns[1].get_text()` directly

Comment: I think amend your title as it is not for any site but for a specific site. You will need different solutions based on how sites load tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scrape a table from web, you can use pandas library.

```py
import pandas as pd
url = 'valid_url'
df = pd.read_html(url)
print(df[0].head())
```

Comment: This is cool. without even using beautifulSoup, this is able to extract the table to the dataframe. But it giving one error:  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: Hey! It gives you a list of dataframes. For example, if you have more than 1 table in the website, you will need to have a list of dataframes. So, you can do df[0].head(). Or you can just chose any dataframe from the list

Answer (score 1):

The code for scraping is wrong in below parts.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M'
response = requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})

df = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    columns = row.find_all('td') # the first row is returning <th> tags, but since you queried <td> tags, it's returning empty list.
    if len(columns)>0: #In order to skip first row or in general, empty rows, you need to put an if check.
        #Use the indices properly to get different values.
        Postcode = columns[0].get_text()
        Borough =columns[1].get_text()
        Neighbourhood = columns[2].get_text()
        df.append([Postcode,Borough,Neighbourhood])
```

Then again, be careful, using get_text will also return the links and anchor tags intact. You might wanna change the code to avoid that.
Happy web scraping :)

Comment: I am still getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please mention the stacktrace here.

Comment: 'TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-3642947a79d8> in <module>
      4     columns = row.find_all('td')
      5     if len(columns)>0:
----> 6         Postcode = row.columns[0].get_text()
      7         Borough = row.columns[1].get_text()
      8         Neighbourhood = row.column[2].get_text()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'

Comment: I didn't use ```Neighbourhood = row.column[2].get_text() ``` in the solution above. Please see that you have made all the edits per the given solution that I have presented.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know pandas but I use this script to scrape table. Hope it is helpful.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M'
response = requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

tbl= soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
table_dict = {
    "head": [th.text.strip() for th in tbl.find_all('th')],
    "rows": [
        [td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all("td")]
            for tr in tbl.find_all("tr")
                if not tr.find("th")
    ]
}
```